# JS - value from two text inputs and create new elements

Tags: javascript, html, input

Hello again StackOverflow peeps! = )

Now I'm trying to get the value from two textboxes into a div\p\span

So, in the first box I write some text, and in the second a number

Now, when I click the button, its supposed to take the value from box1 and then write it in the div, as many times as the value in box2.

I've gotten it to take the value from box1 to the div, but I can't get it to duplicate it with a numbervalue from box2. I removed my faulty code and whats left is just the copy value to `<p>` thing

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script> 
     function starfire () {

         document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = document.getElementById("boks1").value;
         return true;
     }



 </script>
 </head>
 <header>
 <h1>cake</h1>
 </header>
 <body>
     <input type="text" id="boks1">
     <input type="number" id="boks2">
     <br>
     <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="starfire()">Trykk</button>
     <p id="tekst"></p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help from you awesome people <3 =)

Sincerely
Gruff

Comment: You don't have anything in place to get the value from `boks2`... Also no need for the `return true` also close your inputs with `/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function starfire () {
     var boks1=document.getElementById("boks1").value;
     var boks2=parseInt(document.getElementById("boks2").value);
     var html="";

     for (var i=1; i<=boks2; i++) {
          html+=boks1;
     }

     document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = html;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Mind if I ask a few questions? =)

Like, var html=""; - what is the purpose of that? :)

And, if I want it to line break after each time it writes the code, where would I put that? :)

Thanks again dude!

Comment: hi. `var html` is used as a container while you are building the html in the `for loop`. It's not compulsory, but it's useful in case you want to make several changes along the way before you finally insert it in the DOM.

Comment: To insert line breaks you have to change the line inside the `for loop` - here are 2 options: 1) use `html+=boks1+"<br/>";` or 2) user `html+="<p>"+boks1+"</p>";`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for explaining :)